# What are the benefits of array type hinting in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, type-hinting

What might be some benefits of array type hinting in methods and functions in PHP besides documentation and readability?

Comment: Why downvoting? Explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the sooner you catch an error the easier it is to diagnose.  Type hinging in php allows those errors to occur earlier than if something does wrong down in the function or in functions that it calls.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive answer, is there any performance benefits, though?

Comment: I'm not sure.  Googling brings up conflicting answers.  In theory you'd think knowing the types in advance would prevent additional type checks, but I don't know if php takes advantage of that.